# Laravel download doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to trying to download data but for some reason it doesn't work

view

```
@foreach($files as $file)

  {!! Html::link('public/'.$file->name, $file->name) !!}

@endforeach
```

controller

```
public function download($file_name){
    $file_path = public_path('/'.$file_name);
    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

route

```
Route::get('download/{file}','FilesController@download');
```

I get this error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
```

Comment: What *doesn't work* mean? Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: I'm getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is wrong, you are observing `/download/{file}` but calling `/public/{file}`.

```
{!! Html::link('download/'.$file->name, $file->name) !!}
```